# HTML5 Object (Codebase, Codetype deprecated) which DNN Uses

Tags: html, object, embed, dotnetnuke

This very well could be a very, very stupid question. So I apologize; so I have a client whom doesn't want there Dot Net Nuke skin created in a .ascx format.  So anyways, for some odd reason I've stumbled upon a dilemma.

So in Dot Net Nuke, you could simply do:

```
<object id = "Name" codebase = "Name" codetype = "dotnetnuke/server" >
<!-- Whatever code parameters you want here -->
</object>
```

However, when you use HTML 5 you can't use codebase or codetype anymore as they've become depreciated.  If I simply do:

```
<object id="Name" data="Dot Net Nuke Control" type="dotnetnuke/server" >
```

Would that essentially do the same thing? Essentially DNN uses the codetype attribute to automatically parsed as if it was a flash movie, mp3, or whatever. To avoid XML to define the object.

Or do I have to use the  tag?  Cause I know I could do:

```
<embed src="link to DNN Control" type="dotnetnuke/server">
```

But I'd loose the id, identifier.  Also I'm not even sure it'd parse correctly because it has to be handled as a raw object.

Am I totally lost? Over thinking? Confused all together with the conceptual notion.  Anyways, an explanation of would be awesome.  I'm essentially trying to mimic the first code sample above.  An example of all the criteria I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
<object id="dnnNAV" codebase="NAV" codetype="dotnetnuke/server">
            <param name="ProviderName" value="DDRMenuNavigationProvider">
            <param name="IndicateChildren" value="false">
            <param name="ControlOrientation" value="Horizontal">
            <param name="CSSControl" value="mainMenu">
</object>
```

Any suggestions followed by an explanation would be terrific.  I'm trying to learn I swear.

Comment: Every skin I have ever made or used has been a .ascx file. I think you are over thinking it and your client should be more worried about the end result. Not the file extension. Also, run an HTML validator on dotnetnuke.com - if you are striving for perfect markup you better triple your rate with your client because you have a lot of work ahead of you :)

Comment: I was afraid of that sort of remark. Thank you though for the reply.  A weird dilemma indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Greg,

@Ryan said, Try to go with `html5` and object method with `codetype = "dotnetnuke/server"` and if you are not getting your way ahead, post your problems here!

Comment: Hello Prashant,

I apologize but I don't quite understand your remark?  

The issue I'm having is that they want the skin in HTML5; but HTML5 no longer supports the codetype attribute.  That particular attribute is what Dot Net Nuke uses to correctly parse the skin.  The attribute is it's indicator that this is an object.

So my dilemma is, how can I implement?  If I can't identify the object?  Can I use embed? Can I use object and define codetype in the type parameter?

I'm not quite sure where to go; some of my ideas haven't parsed correctly.  I do appreciate the reply.